# Tender Type vs Payment Method/Type

Tags: naming, domain-model, data-modeling

I'm designing the data model of a payment database.  One of the domain requirement is to keep track of how the customer paid and, if applicable, what was used i.e.: Visa, Amex, etc.

In the past I have used `PaymentMethod` to describe `Cash`, `Credit Card`, or `Check`. But I'd like to use the **most appropriate** name for the corresponding objects, in order to avoid confusion that could lead to bugs.  Searching around the web I've learned that a more proper term to use would be `TenderType`.

However, I'm having trouble finding out how to describe what type of credit card was used (i.e. to describe `Visa`, `MasterCard`, `AMEX`, etc. when the `TenderType` is `Credit Card`, `Debit Card`, or `Gift Card`).

Sure, I can make something up and just use an additional field like `CreditCardType`, but I'd like to know what others are using, if there are any **objective arguments** that could guide the naming choice, and if there would be any best practice on how to structure such data (e.g. foreign key to another table ?).

Comment: `CreditCardType`.

Comment: Who are you making the database for? Ask them what they name these things

Comment: @HorusKol for myself =)

Comment: Ask yourself. ...

Comment: Still - TenderType may be more "proper", but PaymentMethod is more common in accounting systems I've seen and worked with. And RobertHarvey has the right of it with CreditCardType

Comment: @RobertHarvey lol... i did...then I asked, what is everyone else using?

Comment: I did think of @RobertHarvey 's version, but it wouldn't be totally right when you store DebitCard types and other card processing type cards. Sorry I know I didn't say that on the question.

Comment: Then call it `PaymentMethodSubtype`, or simply add `DebitCard` to your list of payment methods.

Comment: Cool. I like it. I was even thinking `PaymentCardType` or something to that nature.

Comment: I still would like to know what others use, but if you put this as an answer I'll accept it within a few days.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is about choosing the correct technical term for a *financial* concept. It is not fundamentally about software engineering. Instead, consider talking with subject matter experts within your organization.

Comment: @amon if Someone suggested to add a field which describes the value through a FK from another table not be considered software engineering? I haven’t seen any suggestions until Christopher’s answer. Would you instead prefer that I also ask about possibly redesigning the database? Also, where would you suggest I ask “the public” for their advise on a topic like this? I already asked it internally with many variations so I turned to this community for some extra options. Thank you.

Comment: what's with the down votes and no comments/reasons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*This is not an opinion based question, as there are clear objective arguments to guide the choice*

**Payment method ?**

`PaymentMethod` is simple, accurate, and understood by anybody. I've seen it in many systems (or some abbreviation of it).

You could indeed ask yourself if you want to have credit card products such as Amex or Visa to be `PaymentMetod` on their own, or an additional attribute to a more general method such as `CreditCard`. This depends on how far you need to go in the details about payment processing.

`PaymentType` could also suit the needs.  However, it could bear some more ambiguity : this term could also mean complete payment vs. partial payment, or direct payment vs. payment on behalf.

**Tender type ?**

`TenderType` seems too [ambiguous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tender#Business_and_finance), because tender mostly refers to some kind of bids/offers (e.g. request for tender, call for tender, etc..).  You'll find out by looking for "tender" in online dictionaries like Oxford, Cambridge or Merriam-Webster.

`LegalTender` could be less ambiguous, and would indeed [refer to a payment method](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/legal-tender). However, this legal term has a very precise legal meaning:

> ***Wikipedia:***  Legal tender is a medium of payment recognized by a legal
>   system to be valid for meeting a financial obligation. Paper
>   currency and coins are common forms of legal tender in many countries.
>   Legal tender is variously defined in different jurisdictions. Formally, it is anything which when offered in payment extinguishes the debt. Thus, personal cheques, credit cards, and similar non-cash methods of payment are not usually legal tender.

This has several consequences:

- its definition depends on the country of the transaction
- in some countries, credit cards are not considered as legal tender, because nobody can be forced to accept them as payment means.

So this term appears to specific for your purpose, and I would advise against it.